# Cascade deleting in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

There are 2 tables

```
create table Category
(
   ID int primary key,
   title nvarchar(50)
)

create table Article
(
   ID int primary key,
   title nvarchar(50),
   body nvarchar(max),
   categoryId foreign key references Category(ID)
)
```

Is it possible to remove an item from table `Category` which has child keys in  table `Article` by `Category.ID`? I mean in a sql stored procedure.

Comment: Do you mean a cascaded delete?

Comment: Yes, I mean a cascade deleting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your schema (I use `SOMECOLUMNAME` because you seem to have elided a column name from your example):

```
create table Article (ID int primary key, title nvarchar(50), SOMECOLUMNNAME nvarchar(max), categoryId foreign key references Category(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

And then you can simply:

```
DELETE FROM Category WHERE ID = @ID
```

If you can't edit the schema, you can use these statements:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM Article WHERE categoryId = @ID
DELETE FROM Category WHERE ID = @ID
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way?

Comment: Any... other way? You can do it in two statements within a transaction.

Comment: Ok, will you provide me an example?

Comment: I've supplied an example I believe you can use.

Comment: <<If you can't edit the schema, you can use these statements:...>> The parameter "categoryId" isn't passed as parameter, it need to delete by "articleId".

Comment: Your question says `Is it possible to remove an item from table Category ... by Category.ID`

Comment: If so, you could  answer: "Yes, it is".